# Android Forced RTL for HTC devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been making use of Forced RTL logic for my app which was left to right it worked fine on almost all devices except for the HTC devices. And now I wonder what could be the reason for it.

In my application's manifest I have set following:

```
android:supportsRtl="true" for <application> tag
android:configChanges="locale" for MainActivity
```

Then, in the main activity of the app, in onCreate() method, I have added following code to force Arabic layout after super.onCreate() and before setContentView().

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.locale = new Locale("ar");
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());}
```

But still its not working for HTC, please let me know if there is any other solution to do it for HTC and if not is there any tool that can help me to convert my layouts to RTL.

Comment: What is the android version? RTL only works on android version 4.2 and above.

Comment: I tired it on HTC desire 500 & HTC one both running on 4.1.2 these are the once that are creating problems, so if its only for android versions above 4.2 then what could be the possible solutions for backward support?

Comment: No but you can create customize components like actionbar to achieve RTL.

Comment: My app is using action bar but even if it work what about the rest of app, How will I be able to change those? Or do I have to work on layouts?

Comment: The main problem in RTL apps is actionbar. for rest of app you can work on layouts.